# How to access a parent class attribute without breaking data encapsulation?

Tags: oop, subclass, encapsulation, protected

In the 1994 book *[Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)* by the "Gang of Four", I noticed in the C++ code examples that all *methods* are either declared as `public` or `protected` (never as `private`) and that all *attributes* are declared as `private` (never as `public` or `protected`).

In the first case, I suppose that the authors used `protected` methods instead of `private` methods to allow implementation inheritance (subclasses can delegate to them).

In the second case, while I understand that avoiding `public` and `protected` attributes prevents breaking data encapsulation, **how do you do without them if a subclass need access a parent class attribute?**

For example, the following Python code would have raised an `AttributeError` at the `get_salary()` method call if the `_age` attribute was `private` instead of `protected`, that is to say if it was named `__age`:

```python
class Person:

    def __init__(self, age):
        self._age = age  # protected attribute


class Employee(Person):

    def get_salary(self):
        return 5000 * self._age


Employee(32).get_salary()  # 160000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found out an obvious solution by myself: redeclaring the `private` attribute of the parent class in the subclass:

```python
class Person:

    def __init__(self, age):
        self.__age = age  # private attribute


class Employee(Person):

    def __init__(self, age):
        self.__age = age  # private attribute

    def get_salary(self):
        return 5000 * self.__age


Employee(32).get_salary()  # 160000
```